# Relation between mean width and diameter

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

> Question: Let $A$ be a compact set in $\mathbb R^n$. Is it always true that $\text{mean-width}(A) \ge C \cdot \text{diam}(A)$ for some constant $C$ depending only on the dimension? If not, is it true assuming $A$ is convex?

Background / definitions:

Given a compact set $A\subset\mathbb R^n$ and a direction $v\in\mathcal{S}^{n-1}$, the width $b(A, v)$ is the distance between two supporting hyperplanes of $A$ in the directions $v$ and $-v$, as illustrated in the following figure borrowed from M. Moszynska's *Selected topics in convex geometry*:

[image: Illustration of directional width]

One can define the *minimal width*, *diameter* and *mean width* of $A$ as the minimum value of $b(A, v)$, the maximum value of $b(A, v)$ and the integral mean over $v\in\mathcal S^{n-1}$ of $b(A,v)$, respectively.

The following is obvious:

$$\text{min-width}(A) \le \text{mean-width}(A) \le \text{diam}(A)$$

It is also easy to see that the min-width and the diameter are "independent": They can be equal (i.e. in a ball), or they can be very different (i.e. a long thin tube).

However for the mean-width I don't understand the situation. Can it be that the mean width is arbitrarily small with a fixed diameter?

Comment: I think usually diameter refer to the maximum of the distance between two points of the set. I think it would be more coherent to call what you are considering maximal width or $\mathrm{max-width}$.
I just want to point out that $\mathrm{diam(A)}\geq \mathrm{max-width}(A)$ and that the inequality is in most cases strict.
Nevertheless your question is really clear and well formulated with the definitions included so I guess this is not so important.

Comment: Aren't they equal in the case of a compact set? Or at least compact and convex?

Comment: Consider this argument: Let L be the line segment connecting the two farthest points in A. Its length is the diameter. Now construct two hyperplanes perpendicular two it at its endpoints. By definition of L, no point in A can lie beyond the hyperplanes, therefore it is also the maximal width.

Comment: oh! Sorry! you are totally right. I wrote this comment too fast apparently. Indeed it is quite an interesting fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $L$ be any line segment; then
$$ \frac{w(A)}{\text{diam}(A)} \ge \frac{w(L)}{\text{diam}(L)} $$
(where $w(\cdot)$ denotes mean width).  Note that $w/\text{diam}$ is invariant under scaling, translation, and rotation, so the value of the RHS doesn't depend on which line segment you choose.  In particular, the RHS depends only on the dimension, as desired (and in fact it turns out to be roughly $1/\sqrt{2\pi n}$).  To prove the inequality, take $L$ to be a line segment joining two points in $A$ that realize the diameter of $A$, and then note $A\supseteq L$ (if $A$ is convex, which we may assume wlog since replacing $A$ with its convex hull doesn't change its widths, or its diameter, or its compactness).

(This argument, slightly generalized, appears in A. D. Aleksandrov, "On Mean Values of Support Functions", *Soviet Math. Dokl.* **8** (1967), 149–153, but I wouldn't be at all surprised to learn that it was known decades earlier.)

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you very much :)